# misalignment in different devices with same layout

Tags: android

Here is my xml file ,it is looking good in mpdi resolutions screens but xhdpi not adjusting ,here i am using all 4 types of images but not getting how to fix this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/playbuttonbg" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonshuffle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonplay"
        android:layout_marginLeft="195dp"
        android:background="@drawable/continuousbuttonbg" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonpause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonplay"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pausebuttonbg" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post images of what you get?

Comment: how you want to align this button?

Comment: Didn't get whats your problem??and what its now??

Comment: @Seraphim images added ,could you please look in to it.

Comment: In Relative layout this happens in most case.. Best way is to use LinearLayout.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to align... All buttons horizontally?

Comment: Why you've deleted the images? A image always is worth a thousand words! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, simply:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/playbuttonbg" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonshuffle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonplay"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonplay"
        android:background="@drawable/continuousbuttonbg" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonpause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonplay"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonplay"
        android:background="@drawable/pausebuttonbg" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And yes, you can adjust the margin of the buttons to have some overlay to the central button.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use LinearLayout instead of Relative, and use the **weight** property.

Try something like this

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="3">

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/playbuttonbg"
     />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/continuousbuttonbg"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/pausebuttonbg"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

Adjust the other properties accordingly.

Hope this helps

Comment: Problem is in adjustment only @ sairam